# Heroku FFMPEG Postprocessing error with yt-dlp DownloadError

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg

I am building a discord music bot that uses FFMPEG to download and play the music. yt-dlp seems to not be able to find the ffmpeg file for some reason although I give it the direct path. It works perfectly fine whe I run it on my cpu, but it doesn't work in heroku.

Here's the error in heroku:

```sh
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047823+00:00 app[worker.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047823+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047825+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047854+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047855+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047856+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/engine.py", line 97, in on_reaction_add
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047856+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ydl.download([f'{result["link"]}'])
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047863+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 3212, in download
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047863+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.__download_wrapper(self.extract_info)(
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047865+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 3185, in wrapper
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047865+00:00 app[worker.1]:     res = func(*args, **kwargs)
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047875+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1372, in extract_info
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047876+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self.__extract_info(url, self.get_info_extractor(ie_key), download, extra_info, process)
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047877+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1381, in wrapper
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047877+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047891+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1465, in __extract_info
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047891+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047893+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1517, in process_ie_result
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047894+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ie_result = self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047894+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 2607, in process_video_result
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047894+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.process_info(new_info)
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047896+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 3161, in process_info
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047896+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.report_error('Postprocessing: %s' % str(err))
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047904+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 930, in report_error
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047904+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.trouble(f'{self._format_err("ERROR:", self.Styles.ERROR)} {message}', *args, **kwargs)
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047905+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 871, in trouble
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047905+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
2022-02-14T00:34:29.047921+00:00 app[worker.1]: yt_dlp.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: Postprocessing: ffprobe and ffmpeg not found. Please install or provide the path using --ffmpeg-location
```

Here's my setup:
![root level directory]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKo8L.png

Here's the code:

```py
yt_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'ffmpeg_location': './FFMPEG_CONFIG/ffmpeg.exe',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }]
    }
# Getting Song From Thy YOUTUBE
     await channel.send("> Getting Song From Youtube")
     with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(yt_opts) as ydl:
          ydl.download([f'{result["link"]}'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this:

```js
'ffmpeg_location': './FFMPEG_CONFIG/ffmpeg.exe',
```

`ffmpeg.exe` is a *Windows* binary. It cannot be used on Heroku (and should not be part of your repository to begin with).

Most users who want to use `ffmpeg` on Heroku use [the buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/ffmpeg/ffmpeg) (see also [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app)), e.g.:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git
```

Then remove that hard-coded `ffmpeg_location`, commit, and redeploy. Your app should find `ffmpeg`.

For local development you have a couple of of options:

- Update your `PATH` to make sure `ffmpeg.exe` can be found
- Update your code to set an `ffmpeg_location`, ideally from an environment variable